# why there is a empty area in the upside of my UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqcZv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBIII.png)

Hi guys, I need some help to solve problems
i do not know why there is an empty area in my UITableViewCell like in the picture
and when I continnue to drop up the table, the blue UITextView will disappear，then the next cell appears.Anyone know Why?

```
    @implementation TableCellModel 
+(UITableViewCell *) getCellOfFreeChampionsList
{
    UITableViewCell * tableCell = [[super alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NULL];
    UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.tag = 11;
    textView.text = @"1qaz2wsxE";
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 20);
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [tableCell.contentView addSubview:textView];

//    UILabel * la = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//    la.frame = CGRectMake(5, 50, 70, 20);
//    la.tag = 12;
//    [tableCell.contentView addSubview:la];

    NSLog(@"%@", textView.text);
    NSLog(@"count is %lu", (unsigned long)tableCell.subviews.count);

    return tableCell;
}


    @implementation TableViewDataSource

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableCell;
@synthesize LHfetchedResultsController;
@synthesize numberOfRows;
@synthesize dataTemp;
@synthesize paused;

-(id)initWithTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView = tableView;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}



-(void)dateSourceWithChineseNewestVideos:(NSArray *)videosResults
{
    self.dataTemp = videosResults;
    self.tableCell = [TableCellModel getCellOfFreeChampionsList];
    self.numberOfRows = videosResults.count;
    NSInteger n = self.numberOfRows;
    if (self.numberOfRows == 0) {
        self.numberOfRows = 1;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




//    [self configCellData:indexPath cell:self.tableCell];
    if (self.dataTemp.count < 0) {
        NSArray * arr = self.dataTemp;
        NSInteger n = arr.count;
        NSInteger indexNum = indexPath.row;
        ChineseNewestVideos * re1 = [self.dataTemp objectAtIndex:indexNum];
        UITextView * textView = [tableCell viewWithTag:11];
        textView.text = re1.title;


        NSLog(@"text is %lu",(unsigned long)tableCell.subviews.count);
        NSLog(@"text is %@",textView.text);

//        UILabel * la = [tableCell viewWithTag:12];
//        la.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lD",(long)n];
    }


    return self.tableCell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.LHfetchedResultsController.sections[section];
//    self.numberOfRows = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
    return self.numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: No Error, start from `-(void)dateSourceWithChineseNewestVideos:(NSArray *)videosResults`, videosResults is data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because i declare `UITableViewCell` outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after i move it in it works

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically:

```
// Objective-C
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;


// Swift
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Using Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: hi brother  u know my UITableView is a proprty, it does not have controller, so how and where could code it `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Comment: The reason is that when the viewController extends its edges, let's say under the top bar, the tableView's scrollView automatically adjusts its inset top, so that the content of the tableView will start exactly under the top bar. But in your case this is not needed, since your tableView itself starts under the bar.

Comment: or try to add self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0) in viewDidLoad

Comment: another option is to disable automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets. But not in the UITableView in the Container but in the View which contains the ContainerView.

Comment: Hi bro   my struct is like this   'ViewController' contains 'UINavigationBar' 'UITableView' 'UITabBar'  and they are three properties of 'ViewController'         so I need to add code 'self.tableView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO'    or    'self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)' in  'viewDidLoad' of 'ViewController'   right?    I tried     the first one does not work   but the second works   so does that mean i need to set different 'contentInset' for different iphones?

Comment: Hi bro  the issue has been fixed    the problem is  because i declare tablecell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath  after i move it in it works   however thank you for let me know new knowledge